# Nearly-wrapping TextView is clipping ImageView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

I have a horizontal LinearLayout set to wrap_content. Inside is a vertical LinearLayout containing a single TextView that allows multiple lines (also wrap_content) and an ImageButton (wrap_content). Several of the components have margins and padding so things space out nicely.

When the text in the TextView is short, everything is fine. When the text wraps to multiple lines, still fine. When the text is *almost* long enough to wrap, the ImageButton gets clipped horizontally - its left and right sides are lopped off. If I pull out the margins and padding it works, but of course it doesn't look good.

My guess is that the layout system is calculating the text width without taking into account some of the margins and padding. Then it's laying things out, and there's less total space than that first pass at the TextView thought, so it's clipping the second item in the layout and honoring the calculated TextView width. But that is just a guess.

Short of writing my own layout, any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here's a screen shot from hierarchy viewer, showing where the ImageButton is clipped and with the relevant XML highlighted. The ImageButton's bounds are consistent with what I'm seeing: 27dp wide, whereas the circle image itself is actually 36dp wide, and the ImageButton has 4dp padding specified on each side.

[image: Screen shot of hierarchy viewer]

Again, I had to choose that text carefully: any shorter and the button is fine; longer and it would wrap, and the button's fine again.

**EDIT**

And, here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/messageBubble"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/message_bubble_min_height"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/message_bubble_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/message_bubble_inset"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/message_inbound_padding_inside"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/message_bubble_padding_outside"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/message_bubble_padding_inside"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/message_bubble_padding_v"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/message_bubble_padding_v"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/messageBody"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/message_body_margin_outside"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/message_body_margin_inside"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/message_body_margin_v"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/message_body_margin_v"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/view_message_action_btn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the included view_message_action_btn:

```
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/actionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/action_btn"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/message_action_btn_padding_h"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/message_action_btn_padding_h" />
```

Comment: did you use hierarchyviewer? if so how does the layout looks like (right bottom window)?

Comment: See above...I added a screen shot from hierarchy viewer.

Comment: i meant this part where views are shown as red framrs (you can use a checkbox to swich to white background if it looks better)

Comment: I'm confused. You can see a red frame around the ImageButton in the screen shot I posted...I can mouse over other views and see frames around them too. (The TextView next to it has a frame just around its text, and the LinearLayout surrounding it is just a tiny bit bigger and right up against the ImageButton.) Are you talking about something else?

Comment: ok, post your layout xml file also

Comment: Added the XML as requested. Thanks.

Comment: strange, i couldnt reproduce your problem, in fact i didnt see ImageButton at all, until i set layout_weight="1" for inner LinearLayout

Comment: That's what we ended up doing as well. Which doesn't make sense to me...why would that fix it?